# What is the variance of a Polya Gamma distribution?

Tags: logistic, mathematical-statistics, variance, sampling

I have a simple application that needs the variance of a Polya Gamma distribution (I know the mean since I found it here- http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0310).

This paper says that there is a closed form solution for the variance, but I am not really a mathematician and cannot calculate it.

In short, does anyone know the closed form solution for the variance of the Polya Gamma distribution.

I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 9):

In equation (6), the paper obtains the Laplace transform of these distributions as

$$\phi(t) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{t}{d_k}
\right)^{-b};\ d_k = 2\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2 + c^2/2$$

where $b\gt 0$ and $c\in \mathbb R$ are the parameters.  Taking logarithms yields

$$\psi(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\phi(t) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty -b \log\left(1 + \frac{t}{d_k}\right).$$

This is a [cumulant generating function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cumulant.html) (for imaginary values of $t$, at any rate) whose Taylor series around $t=0$ begins

$$\psi(t) = -\mu_1^\prime t + \frac{1}{2!} \left( \mu_2^\prime - \mu_1^{\prime \,2} \right)t^2 + \cdots$$

with $\mu_j^\prime$ representing the raw moment of order $j$: thus, the negative of the coefficient of $t$ is the mean and twice ($=2!$) the coefficient of $t^2$ is the variance.  The summation formula for $\psi$ can be expanded term-by-term and collected in common powers of $t$ to produce

$$\psi(t) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty -b \left(\frac{t}{d_k} + \frac{t^2}{2 d_k^2} + \cdots\right) = -b\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{d_k} t - b\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2d_k^2} t^2 + \cdots.$$

Such sums, whose terms are the reciprocals of quadratic (and higher) functions of the integral index $k$, are straightforward to evaluate using the [Weierstrass Factorization Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) and yield

$$\mu_1^\prime = \frac{b }{2 c}\tanh \left(c/2\right);\ \mu_2^\prime - \mu_1^{\prime\,2} = \frac{b }{4 c^3}(\sinh (c) - c) \text{sech}^2\left(c/2\right).$$

The former agrees with the mean reported in the paper (adding some confidence to the overall correctness of this approach) while the latter answers the question: it is a closed form expression for the variance.  (These series can be continued in higher powers of $t$ to develop closed formulas for any cumulants, from which higher moments can be extracted.)

Partial contour plots show that the signs of the results (at least) are correct.

[image: Figures]

Nothing is shown along the $b$ axis (where $c=0$) because these formulas are not defined for $c=0$.  However, the plots make it clear that the formulas can be extended to continuous functions along that axis by taking the limits as $c\to 0$.  They give $b/4$ for the mean and $b/24$ for the variance.

Comment: Thanks very very much, this is just what I wanted and very useful. Thanks again